# Batch File - Passing Multiple Inputs

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, automation

I have a batch file that i am working on that will take user input and perform an action based on that input information. My question is, instead of having to run the file over and over again putting in a file type one by one, how can I write it to where a user can put in multiple options. (file1, file2, file3). This is what it looks like now:

```
set /p FileType=Enter file type here: (this is where I would like the user to be able to put in more than just one file type if needed.)
```

Thank you!

Comment: I feel like there's more to your code that what you're showing, because what you've posted works perfectly.

Comment: Are you looking for a `for` loop/ `for /?` to help with that, just set a delimiter to say, a comma.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Yeah, it works but only with 1 input (if that makes sense.) I want to be able to put in txt,xlsx, docx instead of running the batch file over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a loop that parses the user input.  This is one way to do it:

```
set /p "FileType=Enter file type(s) here (ex: txt, pdf, docx): "
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=, " %%A in ("%FileType%") do (
    set ftA=%%A
    set ftB=%%B
    set ftC=%%C
)
dir *.%ftA% *.%ftB% *.%ftC%
```

This has its limitations.  Primarily, it's not very scalable.  You have to add additional variables to the code (ftD, ftE, etc.) be able to handle more than 3 parameters.  Further, as written above, if fewer than 3 parameters are given, the remaining variables are still set, but with a blank value.  This means that you'd have to check that the variable has a value (`if not "%ftC%"==""`) before you can reliably use it.

If you don't need to actually *pass* the user input as a variable to use later, you can loop through the user input directly as @SomethingDark suggests.

```
set /p "FileType=Enter file type(s) here (ex: txt pdf docx): "
for %%A in (%FileType%) do (dir *.%%A)
```

Comment: You don't even need a `for /f ` loop, just a regular `for` loop: `for %%A in (%FileType%) do whatever`

Comment: @SomethingDark How do you pick up additional tokens without the `/f`?

Comment: Regular `for` iterates over every item in the list. The list is separated by either spaces or commas, so `for %%A in (%filetype%) do echo %%A` when `%FileType%` is equal to `pdf txt docx` or `pdf,txt,docx` will both result in `echo pdf` followed by `echo txt` followed by `echo docx`.

Comment: Simpler: `for %%A in (*.%FileType: = *.%) do echo Processing file: %%A` (when the list is separated by spaces)